# Замена гласных в строке на определённый паттерн

Tags: c#, строки

Надо *зашифровать* строку, ищем гласную и сразу после нее добавляем 'к' + эта гласная. Набросал по-нубски, а оно не работает (((( В чём проблема?

```
char vordchek(char a)
    {
        int b = a;
        switch (b)
        {
            case 1072:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1086:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1091:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1101:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1099:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1103:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1105:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1102:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1077:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1080:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1040:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1054:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1059:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1069:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1067:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1071:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1070:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1045:
                {
                    return a;
                }
            case 1048:
                {
                    return a;
                }
        }
        return 't';
    }


    void encryptvord(string vord)
    {
        char[] vord2 = new char[vord.Length * 2 + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < vord.Length; j++)
        {
            vord2[j] = vord[j];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < vord.Length; i++)
        {
            char a = vordchek(vord[i]);
            if (a != 't')
            {
                for(int ii = vord.Length; ii > i; ii--)
                {
                    vord2[ii + 3] = vord2[ii + 1];
                }
                vord2[i+1] = 'к';
                vord2[i + 2] = a;
            }
        }
        for(int ren = 0; ren < vord2.Length; ren++)
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + vord2[ren];
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vord = textBox1.Text;
        encryptvord(vord);
    }
```

Comment: Если ваш код работает неправильно - то приведите пример правильный, как должно работать. Слово "до", слово "после". Пример "Африка" -> "кАфркикка", так? И какой у вас язык - только русский? Русский и английский? Только английский?

Answer (score 3):

В вашем коде очень много вещей, которые стоит переделать.

Во-первых, можно упростить запись switch...case. Одинаковые case можно схлопнуть. Вместо

```
case 1072:
    {
        return a;
    }
case 1086:
    {
        return a;
    }
```

Напишите

```
case 1072:
case 1086:
        return a;
```

Кроме того, есть замечательный оператор default.

И ещё непонятно визуально, что такое 1072 - это буква "а"? Буква "б"? Или "е"?

Ну да ладно, это просто заметка на полях. Мне кажется, что мы вообще избавимся от этого switch...case.

Во-вторых, вместо класса string (при каждом изменении строки создаётся новый объект строки, очень нерациональный подход по отношению к оперативной памяти) привыкайте использовать класс StringBuilder в случаях, когда вы исходную строку часто модифицируете.

В общем, у меня выходит как-то вот так:

```
void Main()
{
    var sourceText = "Африка";
    var result = transformWord(sourceText);
    result.Dump();
}

public bool IsVowel(char letter)
{
    var vowels = new[] {'А','Е','Ё','И','О','У','Ю','Я'};
    var letterCapital = Char.ToUpper(letter);
    return vowels.Any(x => x == letterCapital);
}

public string transformWord(string source)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if(IsVowel(source[i]))
        {
            sb.Append("к");
        }
        sb.Append(source[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

С учётом того, что я не знаю, какой у вас язык текста оставлю замечание, что стало гораздо проще менять набор гласных, без заморочек с определением их кода.

Comment: (+) только одну поправку предлагаю. Функцию ToUpper перенести в IsVowel, так как это зона ответственности функции проверки.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Логично. Вообще, она там и была в исходной версии, но я решил сэкономить одну строку и вытащил её наружу.

Answer (score 3):

```
static string SuperWord(string word)
{
   string pattern = "[аеёиоуэюя]";
   string substitution = "$&к$&";
   return Regex.Replace(word, pattern, substitution, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Вот и вся ваша шифровка

Comment: Сюда очень хорошо подходит [фраза](https://habrahabr.ru/post/63944/) "Если у вас была проблема и вы использовали для её решения регэкспы - то у вас стало на одну проблему больше" )) Регэкспы здесь - это из пушки по-воробьям. Однако решение рабочее, поэтому плюс поставил. И раз уж так, то тема ждёт адского linq-однострочника )))

Comment: Вообще огонь решение! ))

Comment: @AK ну паттерн и подстановку можно завернуть в аргументы без объявления, однострочник хоть и без linq)

Comment: А можно объяснить что это означает  `string substitution = "$&к$&";`, что-то не могу понять, и найти где почитать в интернете

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин подстановка такая, в данном случае заменяет вхождение паттерна на вхождение + "к" + вхождение. `$&` добавляет вхождение паттерна в подстановку.

Comment: А почему `$&` и до и после идёт?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну как я понял автора вопроса нам нужно чтобы каждая гласная заменялась на "гласная + к + гласная"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74293/discussion-between---and-yolosora).